# Swing and AWT GLCanvas Flickering/Blinkering

Tags: java, swing, opengl, jogl

I am doing an UI using Swing to create the components and GLCanvas (com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas) to create my window.

The problem is the next.

In the init state, all work well, but when I drag the window to resize it, the JPanel that contains my GLCanvas starts to flick/blink.

Reading other topics, I try the flag
System.setProperty("sun.awt.noerasebackground", "true"); but it doesnt work.

The override method Init that extends from GLCanvas my class.

```
public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

    this.drawable=drawable;
    gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    //glu = new GLU();
    //glut = new GLUT();
    gl.setSwapInterval(1);
    gl.glClearColor(getClearColor().getRed(),getClearColor().getGreen(),getClearColor().getBlue(), 1.0f);
//*******************************
SetDefaultGLproperty();
System.setProperty("sun.awt.noerasebackground", "true");
System.out.println("PROPERTY ACTIVATE");
//SetDefaultLigthModel();

}
```

Display Method:

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
  try{  
    //System.out.println("display de jcadcanvas");
    //gestion de la vista
    if (Scene.view.isSelectionMode || Scene.view.isMouseOver){
        //System.out.println("entra");
     startPicking( Scene.view.curX,Scene.view.curY);
     gl.glMultMatrixf(Scene.view.trackball.getRotMatrix(), 0);
     if (Scene!=null) Scene.DrawSceneInSelectionMode(gl);
     int r=endPicking(gl);
    if (r!=0) {
       if (Scene.view.isSelectionMode) {
           //System.out.println("select");
             Scene.selectionModel.addSelectedEntity(r);
             //isSelectionMode=false;
               } else
       if (Scene.view.isMouseOver) {
             Scene.selectionModel.setMouseOverEntity(r);
             //isMouseOver=false;
               }
     }

     //isMouseOver=false;
    }
    Scene.view.isSelectionMode=false;
     Scene.view.isMouseOver=false;
    //else { //*/*************************************



    if (Scene.view.fitView) {
        ZoomAll();
        Scene.view.fitView=false;
    } else
        SetOrthoProjection(Scene.view.leftViewVolume, Scene.view.rightViewVolume, Scene.view.bottomViewVolume, Scene.view.topViewVolume, Scene.view.nearViewVolume, Scene.view.farViewVolume);
    //System.out.println(Scene.leftViewVolume+" "+Scene.rightViewVolume+" "+Scene.bottomViewVolume+" "+ Scene.topViewVolume+" "+ Scene.nearViewVolume+" "+ Scene.farViewVolume);
     gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (Scene.view.isZoomBox) DrawZoomBox() ;  ///caja de zoom
    gl.glMultMatrixf(Scene.view.trackball.getRotMatrix(), 0);
 /*
   if (!Scene.getSelectedNode().isEmpty()){
    JAbstractEntity centro=(JAbstractEntity)Scene.getSelectedNode().get(0);
    JPoint p=centro.getCentroid();
    gl.glTranslated(-p.x, -p.y,-p.z);
   }
  * */
    if (isDrawaxes()) {
        DrawAxes(gl);
    }
    if (Scene!=null) Scene.DrawScene(gl);
    //}

  } catch(com.jogamp.opengl.GLException e){

  }catch(java.util.ConcurrentModificationException e){

  }

  if (save) save();
}
```

And the Reshape method:

```
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    //AQUI ESTA EL PROBLEMA DEL RESHAPE
    System.out.println(width+"entro"+height);
    double left = Scene.view.leftViewVolume;
    double right = Scene.view.rightViewVolume;
    double bottom = Scene.view.bottomViewVolume;
    double top = Scene.view.topViewVolume;
    if (width != aWidth) {
        System.out.println("ancho");
        double magnitud = ((Scene.view.rightViewVolume - Scene.view.leftViewVolume) * (double) height) / (double) width;
        magnitud = ((Scene.view.topViewVolume - Scene.view.bottomViewVolume) - magnitud) / 2.0;
        left = Scene.view.leftViewVolume;
        right = Scene.view.rightViewVolume;
        //bottom=topViewVolume-magnitud;
        bottom = Scene.view.bottomViewVolume + magnitud;
        top = Scene.view.topViewVolume - magnitud;
    } else if (height != aHeight) {
            System.out.println("alto");
        double magnitud = ((Scene.view.topViewVolume - Scene.view.bottomViewVolume) * (double) width) / (double) height;
        magnitud = ((Scene.view.rightViewVolume - Scene.view.leftViewVolume) - magnitud) / 2.0;
        left = Scene.view.leftViewVolume + magnitud;
        right = Scene.view.rightViewVolume - magnitud;
        bottom = Scene.view.bottomViewVolume;
        top = Scene.view.topViewVolume;
    }

    aHeight = height;
    aWidth = width;
    //System.out.println (aHeight+" "+aWidth);
    //System.out.println (width +" "+height);
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    SetOrthoProjectionIsotropic(left, right, bottom, top, Scene.view.nearViewVolume, Scene.view.farViewVolume);
    //fitView=true;
}
```

Anyone knows any solution?

Thanks for your time

I am using GL2 with the JOGAMP libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the property sun.awt.noerasebackground in command line if possible, earlier for sure. However, this workaround no longer works due to a regression in AWT, there is a bug report against JOGL about that but it can't be fixed within JOGL: https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1182

You can try to replace the GLCanvas by a GLJPanel but I'm not sure that you will obtain a better result.

Please be more accurate about your hardware, your operating system, your Java version, the JOGL version (2.3.2?), ...

By the way, replace glu = new GLU() by GLU.createGLU(gl) if you want to avoid catching some UnsupportedOperationException instances.

Comment: I cannot change GLCanvas for GLJPanel. Mi Hardware is: i7, 3,40GHz, 4GB RAM, W7 Home Premium x64, and GT520. I use the newest version of JOGL and I use OpenGL 2.X

Comment: Please can you at least give it a try? Replacing GLCanvas by GLJPanel isn't very difficult. Please explain why you claim to be unable to change GLCanvas for GLJPanel. Your init method overrides GLEventListener, not GLCanvas. There is some confusion in your post.

Comment: I find the error. It is in the pick event, I use normal buffers (with allocate) instead of DirectBuffers

Comment: I don't see how it would cause this problem even though passing an indirect NIO buffer to JOGL is a bad idea (just possible for convenience) as JOGL will have to make a direct NIO buffer with it to communicate with native OpenGL anyway.